# OpenCV and Qt: Mat to QLabel QPixmap

Tags: qt, opencv

I'm having some trouble with the following code. I'm attempting to set a Mat as a QLabel pixmap. When I call QLabel::setPixmap(), nothing happens! The label in the dialog box stays exactly the same, showing placeholder text. It has been properly promoted to MyLabel.

```
//include stuff above
MyLabel::MyLabel(QWidget *parent): QLabel(parent)
{
    boats = cv::imread("C:/boats.jpg");
    setPixmap(boats);
}

void MyLabel::setPixmap(cv::Mat image){
    cv::Mat converted;
    cv::cvtColor(image, converted, CV_BGR2RGB);
    QImage result = QImage((const unsigned char*)(converted.data),
                           converted.cols, converted.rows, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    QLabel::setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(result));

}
```

I have also tried setting the pixmap in the following way:

```
QLabel::setPixmap(QPixmap("C:/boats.jpg"));
```

But this produces the same effect. Any ideas?

Comment: try to create a signal that sends the pixmap and conncect it to the slot of the label.

Answer (score 1):

You should set image to the interface. For instance, you can set like this way:

```
 ui->label_15->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(result));
```